# MySQLWorkbench crashes on macOS Ventura 13.2 when trying to execute "show tables"

Tags: mysql-workbench, macos-ventura

Title says it all.
Latest version of MySQLWorkbench (`8.0.32`) crashes on macOS 13.2 when trying to execute "show tables".
On mysql in the terminal on the other hand the command works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install previous version of MySQLWorkbench, `8.0.31`.

Be aware that I could not find a way to install a specific version of MySQLWorkbench through `homebrew`, so you need to download and install it manually from the [website](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/).